DS160 changes in visa category
My family's previous DS160s confirmation had B1/B2 category with business/tourism class and we used those to book appointments. The appointment confirmation only shows B2 as visa and business/tourism as class.
The DS160 expired so I created a new one by retrieving the old application and I can take both old and new to the appointments. But this time I only filled B2 (tourism/medical) in DS160 while editing the form instead of B1/B2 (business/tourism).

Should I have filled B1/B2 only instead of B2 in the new DS160s?
Will I be asked to book appointments again and pay the visa fee again?
Can I avoid this by again making new DS160 with B1/B2 visa category?

